# Trying to get multiple values under same key name instead of getting last value of key

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I have been trying to solve this for a long time but I haven't found the solution yet. I have a JSON object stringified, which I would like to extract the values written under the same key name. Hence as I write the key, I always get the last value to that key.

I have already tried some methods but no luck. Right now I am trying to call the key but it gets always the last value, also I have tried calling the variable which contains the JSON.parse and adding [0] at the end, for example: variable[0].

```
//this is the stringified JSON below
var json = {"code": "1", "name": "client 1", "code": "2", "name": "client 2", 
            "code": "3", "name": "client 3", "code": "4", "name": "client 4"}

var json_parse = JSON.parse(json);
console.log(json_parse.code + ' - ' + json_parse.name);
```

The actual outcome right now is: '4 - client 4'. While the expected outcome is: '1 - client 1, 2 - client 2, ... 4 - client 4'.

Comment: Well that is not possible. An object can only have one property with that name. You should have an array of objects....

Comment: Try transform your string into an array before parse: `var json = [{"code": "1"}, {"name": "client 1"}, {"code": "2"}, {"name": "client 2"}, {"code": "3"}, {"name": "client 3"}, {"code": "4"}, {"name": "client 4"}]`

Comment: and considering having an array of objects, then how should I call the keys? thanks

Comment: @Ric.H yes I can do that, as its how it was before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do what you want. An object can only have ONE property with name. Any property that comes after it overwrites it. That is why you are only getting the last one. What you have is

```
var json = {"code": "4", "name": "client 4"}
```

You need an array of objects.

```js
var items = [{
    "code": "1",
    "name": "client 1"
  }, {
    "code": "2",
    "name": "client 2"
  },
  {
    "code": "3",
    "name": "client 3"
  }, {
    "code": "4",
    "name": "client 4"
  }
]
items.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item.code, item.name)
})
```

Comment: amazing man :D I have managed to fix the problem thanks to your help!!! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking can not be done.
JSON is a string representation of an object, when converted to a javascript object the keys will become the object's properties, so when the string is decoded you will only get the latest value as it will reassing the values to the same keys over and over.

You should look into JSON representaion of an array:

```
[{"code": "1", "name": "client 1"}, {"code": "2", "name": "client 2"}, 
 {"code": "3", "name": "client 3" }, {"code": "4", "name": "client 4"}]
```

And then, after parsing you can iterate them as :

```
json_parse[0].code,
json_parse[1].code
```

etc